# Ubuntu PCI Passtrough Virtual Box - Locked Machine

Tags: virtualbox, pci, lspci

I am using virtual box with the Ubuntu 14.04 image on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine to test if my "PCI carrier card" is getting recognized by the VM.

After entering "lspci" on the VM I noticed that the PCI device is not listed in the VM.

I found out that I have to pass the PCI device to the VM by typing following command on the host machine:

> f.ex. VBoxManage modifyvm "VMname" --pciattach bus:device.function@bus:device.function

So I typed in following line:

> VBoxManage modifyvm "Ubuntu 14" --pciattach 06:00.0@01:00.0

Output:

> VBoxManage: error: The machine 'Ubuntu 14' is already locked for a session (or being unlocked)
>
> VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
>
> VBoxManage: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Write)" at line 493 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?
I was looking for solutions on the internet for hours. Couldn't find anything that would help me to solve the problem.

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: To be able to attach a PCI device is requested that the VM is turned off and the chipset is set as ICH9.